Не могу понять, в чем заключается ошибка ValueError
def personal_sum(*numbers):
    result = 0
    incorrect_data = 0
    for i in numbers:
        try:
            result += i
        except TypeError:
            print(f'Некорректный тип данных для подсчета суммы – {i}')
            incorrect_data += 1

    return f'Сумма чисел: {result}, количество некорректных данных: {incorrect_data}'

def calculate_average(*numbers):
    try:
        if not isinstance(numbers, (list, tuple)):
            print('В numbers записан некорректный тип данных')
            return None

        total_sum, incorrect_data = personal_sum(numbers)

        count = len(numbers) - incorrect_data 

        average = total_sum / count 
        return average
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return 0  
    except TypeError:
        print('В numbers записан некорректный тип данных')
        return None

# Примеры использования этих функций
print(f'Результат 1: {calculate_average("1, 2, 3")}') 
print(f'Результат 2: {calculate_average([1, "Строка", 3, "Ещё Строка"])}')
print(f'Результат 3: {calculate_average(567)}')  
print(f'Результат 4: {calculate_average([42, 15, 36, 13])}')

Напишите 2 функции:
Функция personal_sum(numbers):
Должна принимать коллекцию numbers.
Подсчитывать сумму чисел в numbers путём перебора и увеличивать переменную result.
Если же при переборе встречается данное типа отличного от числового, то обработать исключение TypeError, увеличив счётчик incorrect_data на 1.
В конечном итоге функция возвращает кортеж из двух значений: result - сумма чисел, incorrect_data - кол-во некорректных данных.
Функция calculate_average(numbers)
Среднее арифметическое - сумма всех данных делённая на их количество.
Должна принимать коллекцию numbers и возвращать: среднее арифметическое всех чисел.
Внутри для подсчёта суммы используйте функцию personal_sum написанную ранее.
Т.к. коллекция numbers может оказаться пустой, то обработайте исключение ZeroDivisionError при делении на 0 и верните 0.
Также в numbers может быть записана не коллекция, а другие типы данных, например числа. Обработайте исключение TypeError выводя строку 'В numbers записан некорректный тип данных'. В таком случае функция просто вернёт None.

ошибку то покажите. Или вопрос подробнее распишите

Добавьте в вопрос полный текст ошибки вместе с трэйсбэком

total_sum, incorrect_data = personal_sum(numbers) # Получаем сумму и количество некорректных данных
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Ты распаковываешь две переменные, total_sum и  incorrect_data из строки personal_sum(numbers).
a, b = 'Какая-та строка' # Ошибка
a, b = 'Значение', 123 # Верно
a, b = ('Значение', 123) # Верно

Я так понял, что нужно в функции personal_sum возвращать не строку, а список/кортеж.

Понял, в чем ошибка. Я f строку использовал, а в этом случае это некорректно
